# How do I enter environmental variables only as a factor (not as continuous variables) in the capscale function?

Tags: r, vector, factors, vegan, cap

I am performing a CAP analysis (vegan, R) on a species abundance table, with 2 explaining factors (Location and Complexity_Watson) and one explaining continuous variable (Depth..m.). 
Below you will find some of my code:

```
species.cap=capscale(Species.MVA.DOV ~ Location + Depth..m. + 
   Complexity_Watson, data=Habitat.MVA.DOV, distance="bray", na.action=na.omit)
```

However, `summary(species.cap)` yields the location & complexity as both constraining (continuous) variables and constraining factors.

How can I make sure it only enters them as factors? (I tried adding `factor()` but that yielded the same result).

When I want to plot the environmental variables, it creates both arrows and centroids for location and complexity, while I only want centroids (and an arrow for depth).

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Use `as.factor` to change the variables to factors in the dataframe`Habitat.MVA.DOV`

```
Habitat.MVA.DOV$Location <- as.factor(Habitat.MVA.DOV$Location)
Habitat.MVA.DOV$Complexity_Watson <- as.factor(Habitat.MVA.DOV$Complexity_Watson)
```

For the plotting question you have to realize that `plot` is calling `plot.cca`. Use the help section in `plot.cca` to pinpoint the solution to your question.

I think what you want is:

```
plot(species.cap, display = "cn") #cn stands for centroid, see help for other options
?plot.cca # gets you to the documentation/help on plot.cca
```

Also, the [vegan tutorial](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/opetus/metodi/vegantutor.pdf) is a great reference with helpful examples.

Comment: Current **vegan** release (2.3-0) indeed requires that your factors are strictly factors and not only factor-looking character strings. This will change in the next release (2.3-1) which also finds centroids for character variables that were not formally defined as factors. This concerns all funtions for constrained ordination (`capscale`, `rda`, `cca`)